# How to use iesProfileURL in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I find in swift documentation about SceneKit the can be used a IES file for the light ambience.
I've tried to setup a basic example but doesn't work and i'm not able to figure why.
Anyone have tried and can give me an example of how to use it?

```
    let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
    sceneView.scene = PrimitivesScene()
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let pathIes = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myIesFile", ofType: "ies")
    let urlIes = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: pathIes!)

    let scene = SCNScene()
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, length: 10.0, chamferRadius: 1.0)
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = .IES
    ambientLightNode.light?.iesProfileURL = urlIes

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
    sceneView.scene = scene
```

Could be the problem the format of the IES file? Which is the specification in case?

My goal is to emit the light from a specific point in the main scene as can you see in the image below. The point could be an image of a product foe example. The light in the picture is the result of "read" the informations of the IES file.

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Can you upload this example with sources to github? :) I want to try.

Comment: @Maetschl my example is nothing more than I wrote. did you mean the ies file?

Comment: Yes, if you upload a github project. we can work on there :)